# Add Entry to Existing XMLFile Python

Tags: python, xml, scripting, web

Look out! Noob Question.

I'm really new to python, (C is my primary) and I'm looking to make some backend scripts for managing my webserver. In order to update the RSS feeds, I need to append entries to an XML File.

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<listofentries>
    <entry>
        <title>SampleTitle</title>
        <pubdate>10/12/12</pubdate>
    </entry>
</listofentries>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<listofentries>
    <entry>
        <title>SampleTitle</title>
        <pubdate>10/12/12</pubdate>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>SampleTitle2</title>
        <pubdate>11/5/12</pubdate>
    </entry>
</listofentries>
```

I need to add another entry in the list of entries. I know i could do it using basic File I/O but that is a noobie thing to do.

I know that the XML parsers are built for this, but I have yet to find a decent tutorial on using them to add new entries instead of just new attributes.

Any and all suggestions welcome. Also please tell me if what Im doing is even smart.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) and its Element.append method.
In that documentation you can find out how to parse the xml into a tree object and then append a new subelement to an existing parent element.

Comment: Yes, basically one would create a data structure in memory representing the XLM already in the file by parsing it in, modify it, then write it back out. See [Modifying an XML File](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file). Also, a little searching reveals that there are quite a number of ElementTree tutorials available. Here's just [one](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) of many the OP could use to get started.